# Creating an array with date information based on two dates

Tags: php, arrays, date, loops, for-loop

I created the following array manually (bottom), I wish to create it programmatically using only two strings which can be easily exploded (explode()).

```
$min_date = '2012-03-01 00:00:00';
$max_date = '2012-04-25 00:00:00';
```

I've already explode() the strings as well as found out how many months are between the two dates

```
    $min_date = explode('-',$min_date);
    $min_date['year'] = intval($min_date[0]);
    $min_date['month'] = intval($min_date[1]);
    $min_date['day'] = intval($min_date[2]);

    $max_date = explode('-',$max_date);
    $max_date['year'] = intval($max_date[0]);
    $max_date['month'] = intval($max_date[1]);
    $max_date['day'] = intval($max_date[2]);

$months_between = ($max_date['month'] - $min_date['month']) + 12 * ($max_date['year'] - $min_date['year']);
```

which returns 1

`cal_days_in_month()` function seems useful too, I just don't know how...

```
$days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year)
```

Here is the array I created manually!

```
$periods = array(
  '0' => array(
    'month'=>'march',
    'week'=>'1',
    'days'=>'4',
    'readable'=>' Thurs Mar, 01, 2012 - Sun Mar, 04, 2012',
    'created_at_min'=>'2012-03-01 00:00:00',
    'created_at_max'=>'2012-03-04 24:00:00'
  ),
  '1' => array(
    'month'=>'march',
    'week'=>'2',
    'days'=>'7',
    'readable'=>' Mon Mar, 05, 2012 - Sun Mar, 11, 2012',
    'created_at_min'=>'2012-03-05 00:00:00',
    'created_at_max'=>'2012-03-11 24:00:00'
  ),
  '2' => array(
    'month'=>'march',
    'week'=>'3',
    'days'=>'7',
    'readable'=>' Mon Mar, 12, 2012 - Sun Mar, 18, 2012',
    'created_at_min'=>'2012-03-12 00:00:00',
    'created_at_max'=>'2012-03-18 24:00:00'
  ),
  '3' => array(
    'month'=>'march',
    'week'=>'4',
    'days'=>'7',
    'readable'=>' Mon Mar, 19, 2012 - Sun Mar, 25, 2012',
    'created_at_min'=>'2012-03-19 00:00:00',
    'created_at_max'=>'2012-03-25 24:00:00'
  ),
  '4' => array(
    'month'=>'march',
    'week'=>'5',
    'days'=>'6',
    'readable'=>' Mon Mar, 26, 2012 - Sun Mar, 31, 2012',
    'created_at_min'=>'2012-03-26 00:00:00',
    'created_at_max'=>'2012-03-31 24:00:00'
  ),
  '5' => array(
    'month'=>'april',
    'week'=>'1',
    'days'=>'1',
    'readable'=>' Sun Apr, 1, 2012',
    'created_at_min'=>'2012-04-01 00:00:00',
    'created_at_max'=>'2012-04-01 24:00:00'
  ),
  '6' => array(
    'month'=>'april',
    'week'=>'2',
    'days'=>'7',
    'readable'=>' Mon Apr, 2, 2012 - Sun Apr, 8, 2012',
    'created_at_min'=>'2012-04-01 00:00:00',
    'created_at_max'=>'2012-04-08 24:00:00'
  ),
  '7' => array(
    'month'=>'april',
    'week'=>'3',
    'days'=>'7',
    'readable'=>' Mon Apr, 9, 2012 - Sun Apr, 15, 2012',
    'created_at_min'=>'2012-04-09 00:00:00',
    'created_at_max'=>'2012-04-15 24:00:00'
  ),
  '8' => array(
    'month'=>'april',
    'week'=>'4',
    'days'=>'7',
    'readable'=>' Mon Apr, 16, 2012 - Sun Apr, 22, 2012',
    'created_at_min'=>'2012-04-16 00:00:00',
    'created_at_max'=>'2012-04-22 24:00:00'
  ),
  '9' => array(
    'month'=>'april',
    'week'=>'5',
    'days'=>'3',
    'readable'=>' Mon Apr, 23, 2012 - Wed Apr, 25, 2012',
    'created_at_min'=>'2012-04-16 00:00:00',
    'created_at_max'=>'2012-04-25 00:00:00' // note last day timestamp needs to be 00:00:00
  ),
);
```

**Is their anything that PHP offers that can be of extreme help before I dive into this?**

```
$weeks = array(
  'may' = array(1,2,3,4,5),
  'april' = array(1,2,3,4,5),
);
```

Comment: `24:00:00` is not a real time... :)

Comment: I was halfway into writing an answer, but I don't have the patience to figure out all the gory details right now. Basically what you're looking for is the [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) function and a lot of the [`date`](http://php.net/date) function. Increment your timestamp created by `strtotime`, looping from your start date to your end date. Get all the info about a particular date using the various options of `date`, then do some math using day-of-week, days-in-a-month, day-of-month etc.

Comment: `strtotime` creates a unix timestamp which would seem kind of nuts to loop through, is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes. Why is it nuts to work with a timestamp which you can easily increment and use with `date`?

Comment: He thinks you meant to loop through each millisecond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$min_date = new DateTime('2012-03-01 00:00:00');
$max_date = new DateTime('2012-04-25 00:00:00');
$numOfWeeks = ceil($min_date->diff($max_date)->days / 7.0);

$baseDate = $min_date->getTimestamp();
$startOfWeek = 'Mon';
for ($i = 0; $i <= $numOfWeeks + 1; $i++)
{
    $weekRangeStart = date('D M, d, Y', $baseDate);
    if (date('M', strtotime("Next Sunday", $baseDate)) == date('M', $baseDate))
    {
        $weekRangeEnd = date('D M, d, Y', strtotime("Next Sunday", $baseDate));
        $nextDateObject = new DateTime(date('r', strtotime('Next Monday', $baseDate)));
    }
    else
    {
        $weekRangeEnd = date('D M, d, Y', strtotime("last day of this month", $baseDate));
        $nextDateObject = new DateTime(date('r', strtotime("last day of this month", $baseDate)));
    }

    $baseDateObject = new DateTime(date('r', $baseDate));

    $daysInWeek = $baseDateObject->diff($nextDateObject)->days;

    $periods[] = array('month' => date('F', $baseDate), 'days' => $daysInWeek, 
                'readable' => $weekRangeStart . ' - ' . $weekRangeEnd);

    if (date('D', $baseDate) != $startOfWeek)
        $baseDate = strtotime("Next Monday", $baseDate);
    else
        $baseDate = strtotime("+1 week", $baseDate);
}

var_dump($periods);
```

Do something like this.  You'll get a an array like:

```
    array
  0 => 
    array
      'month' => string 'March' (length=5)
      'days' => int 4
      'readable' => string 'Thu Mar, 01, 2012 - Sun Mar, 04, 2012' (length=37)
  1 => 
    array
      'month' => string 'March' (length=5)
      'days' => int 7
      'readable' => string 'Mon Mar, 05, 2012 - Sun Mar, 11, 2012' (length=37)
  2 => 
    array
      'month' => string 'March' (length=5)
      'days' => int 7
      'readable' => string 'Mon Mar, 12, 2012 - Sun Mar, 18, 2012' (length=37)
  3 => 
    array
      'month' => string 'March' (length=5)
      'days' => int 7
      'readable' => string 'Mon Mar, 19, 2012 - Sun Mar, 25, 2012' (length=37)
  4 => 
    array
      'month' => string 'March' (length=5)
      'days' => int 5
      'readable' => string 'Mon Mar, 26, 2012 - Sat Mar, 31, 2012' (length=37)
  5 => 
    array
      'month' => string 'April' (length=5)
      'days' => int 7
      'readable' => string 'Mon Apr, 02, 2012 - Sun Apr, 08, 2012' (length=37)
  6 => 
    array
      'month' => string 'April' (length=5)
      'days' => int 7
      'readable' => string 'Mon Apr, 09, 2012 - Sun Apr, 15, 2012' (length=37)
  7 => 
    array
      'month' => string 'April' (length=5)
      'days' => int 7
      'readable' => string 'Mon Apr, 16, 2012 - Sun Apr, 22, 2012' (length=37)
  8 => 
    array
      'month' => string 'April' (length=5)
      'days' => int 7
      'readable' => string 'Mon Apr, 23, 2012 - Sun Apr, 29, 2012' (length=37)
  9 => 
    array
      'month' => string 'April' (length=5)
      'days' => int 0
      'readable' => string 'Mon Apr, 30, 2012 - Mon Apr, 30, 2012' (length=37)
```

EDIT: Code updated so that weeks don't span months.

Comment: This is freaking fantastic, I feel so bad because I can see you put so much work into it. I was using some of your earlier code but ditched the 7 day increment mainly because of the issue with monthly - renewal you can see that pocket `5` of my example array is the start of april. It is again augmented by its DOW day of the week. I'm going to look at this new code. Thanks for developing this further!

Comment: I'm trying to work with your code. There are a couple of issues with it. The first is that I need each week to only contain one month, the `$numOfWeeks` var comes short with this principle (my array length is `9` yours is `8`). In other words I need your pocket `4` to be split at the month. The other fundamental issue is that it is not given that each week will end on a Sunday. Basically I'm trying to get pockets `5` and `9` from my example incorporated. But I just seem to be making a mess of your code. I also need to implement the "week" number as well.

Comment: I believe it could all be solved with a `weeks` array that looks like this (updated post). Alas I have yet to make it.. I think that a month may always have 5 weeks in it unless it starts on a monday? No, this cant be right... If I used weeks and a double loop I could scrap `$numOfWeeks`. Talking this through is helping me a ton, lol

Comment: Does it not end on a sunday? I see that you have a `Sun Apr, 1, 2012` one day week because it's a sunday and the first week is 4 days because you end it on a sunday.

Comment: That is a valid observation. But It's also like that because I want the week to start on a monday. Here is some visual representation. http://imgur.com/a/qL7yB/all

Comment: I updated the code so that the weeks don't span months.  `Mon Mar, 26, 2012 - Sat Mar, 31, 2012` is 5 days instead of going to sunday.  As for the case regarding a month starting on Sunday, I think you can create a conditional to check if `$baseDate` is day 1 and is Sunday.  Then build a different array entry otherwise execute the current code.